# How can I solve this definite integral? 3

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I solve this integral
$$I=\int_0^\pi \frac{w\sin\theta}{(w-k_zv\cos\theta)^2 -k_xv\sin\theta}d\theta$$
I have tried partial fraction and integration formulation but could not get anywhere. Which method should I apply?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution is a sure way to turn a rational trigonometric integral into just rational integral

Comment: Ahan! Thank you. I am going to try this.